# calculate the mid points of a vector using Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I started to learn python from scratch. I got some issues while doing the following problem.

I have the following vector ,`x_vector = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`. Using this vector, I need to create this new vector `x1 = (-0.5,0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5)`.

Basically the desired vector should have first element -0.5, mid points between each elements and the last element +0.5.

The code I tried so far as follows:

```
import numpy as np
x_vector=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
x=len(x_vector)
mid=np.zeros(x+1)

for i in range (0,x):
    if i==0 :
        mid[i]= x_vector[i]-0.5
    else :
        mid[i]=(x_vector[i] + x_vector[i+1])/2
        i +=1
```

Seems like this doesn't give the desired output. Can you one help me to figure out what can I do to get correct output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear whether this is a homework, but given that you are using `numpy` I think it is fair game to use it as its whole potential, in this case you can just do:

```
import numpy as np
x_vector=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) 
a = np.insert(x, 0, x[0] - 1)
b = np.append(x, x[-1] + 1)
mid = (a + b) / 2
```

Comment: Any time you do insert and append, I'd say you aren't using numpy's full potential, but this is a good overall approach nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

Using `itertools.pairwise`:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

res = []
res.append(min(x_vector)-0.5)
res.append(max(x_vector)+0.5)
res.extend([np.mean(z) for z in pairwise(x_vector)])
sorted(res)
```

Output:

```
[-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider, what will happen for `i = 0` and `i = 1` in your loop:

```
mid[0] = x_vector[0] - 0.5 # = -0.5
mid[1] = (x_vector[1] + x_vector[2]) / 2 # (1 + 2) / 2 = 3 / 2 = 1 (or 1.5 if python3)
```

you mismatched indexes.
Try this:

```
for i in range (0,x):
    if i == 0:
        mid[i] = x_vector[i]-0.5
    else :
        mid[i] = (x_vector[i - 1] + x_vector[i]) / 2.0
```

Note, that i changed division to divide by `2.0` instead of `2` - this will make sure, that division result will be double (number with fraction) instead of integer (number without fraction, in python 2 division two integers will round to integer).
Also `i += 1` is redundant, `i` variable in `for loop` will updated (overwriting your `+= 1` statement) every loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you  for your detailed answer. I learnt a lot. But It seems that the code you suggested dont provide the "9.5" , which is the last element of the vector.  Can you suggest anything for that ?

Comment: Use @Sebastian Kreft solution, since you've decided to use numpy, as his solution is most numpy-est. I just wanted to explain, why your code ain't producing result you think it should.

Comment: @ Radosław Cybulski , Thank you for the comment. I just added  mid[i+1]= x_vector[i]+0.5  to  the code segment that you suggested, and that seems working well.